# wordpress - site not update after update style.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I updated the style.css in `Appearance > Theme Editor > stylesheet(style.css)`,
I refresh my site, then I see that the style is not applied.

I've also tried clear cache in browser and use `cmd + shift + r` to re-download the resources but still not working.

Is there any way to make the site live for development, or is there any preferred way for development?

In `style.css`

```
...
/*
Author: xxx Limited
Description: This is the template for xxx
Version: 1.0.0. // tried to update the version here but not working
... 
*/
.....
```

Comment: You should avoid editing through Theme editor at all. Also read this for clear cache - https://www.sunilchauhan.com/learn/what-does-ctrl-shift-r-do-in-chrome/ . You can always change style.css version to force changes. Also disableing cache on your website while developing is the better option. How to disable cache read this - https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/turning-off-caching-using-htaccess .

Comment: @Martin Mirchev Where can I update the version

Comment: Rather a basic suggestion, but have you checked through the theme editor that your changes have been fully saved? Also get a CSS validator to check the file has no errors. Then use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what is setting the styles on the elements you are interested in. There may for example be a class with a higher specificity selector or an !important on a value.

Comment: @CCCC in the begining of style.css you will see a version number.

Comment: @Martin Mirchev please check my update above

Comment: @CCCC Do you have any CDN enabled for the site? If so, you need to clear the CDN's cache as well.

Comment: @Gosi no CND enabled

Answer (score 0):

Need to check few things.

1. upload style.css through ftp or cpanel again to check whether it is properly saved or not,
2. Remove cache , check in private window to make sure that there is no cache.
3. check in console for error if above 2 doesn't work.

Comment: I am updating `style.css` directly in `Appearance > Theme Editor > stylesheet(style.css)`

Comment: Download the same file through ftp to check whether your saved css is there or not

Comment: no other methods to keep it refreshing?

Comment: check in console , is any error there?

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS file has been updated, the problem is because of caching. There are different levels of cache.

- Clear Cloudflare cache if you are using it.
- Clear any caching mechanism that your Webhosting offered.
- Clear all plugins cache

Answer (score 0):

Salman and PHP Geek are right, do the steps they mention that should solve your problem. If the problem continues then...

In function.php find `wp_enqueue_style` function it would look something like this. There can be multiples of them so look for the 'style.css' inside them

`wp_enqueue_style('yourtheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', '1.1.0');`

see the last argument '1.1.0' this could be anything on your case, this can also be a variable. Change this to something else like '1.1.1' (anything other then 1.1.0)

OR

replace the line with the below code (doing this will change your version automatically whenever you change something in the style.css)

```
$ver = filemtime(get_template_directory().'/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('yourtheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', $ver);
```